# PHP is executing a javascript on mouse move over window. It's looping on a function. How can I make it execute only once?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Basically, I have to execute a function on JS, that uses a variable in PHP.
The problem I'm having is that the function on JS is executing constantly.
I need the function to execute when the mouse moves over the page, which works great, except it executes in loop non-stop.

I'm pasting an example code. Any ideas on how to make it execute the JS function only once?
Any help would be greatly appreaciated, I'm not very good at PHP & JS.

```
<?php 

function page()

{

echo 'test text';
}
//page()
?>

<html>
<head>

<title>onmousemove test</title>

<script type="text/javascript">

window.onmousemove = move;
function move() {
    alert("<?PHP page() ?>");
}
</script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a flag. check if the flag is set, if not, execute the code, then set the flag.

```
var stop = false; //flag

function move(){
    if(stop) return; //is the flag true?
    alert("<?PHP page() ?>"); //it wasn't, so alert
    stop = true; //now set it to true so it doesn't fire again
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not looping non-stop, it's just looping whenever you move your mouse...  You should consider `window.onload` instead, this fires automatically when the page is done load.  But since in this post you insist `window.onmousemove`, you can try this:

```
triggered = false;

function move() {
  triggered = true;
  alert("<?php page(); ?>");
}

window.onmousemove = function(){ 
  if (triggered === false) move();
};
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ld0rLtt0/1/)

(P.S. Since you're knew, I'll tell you something.  To except an answer, you click the green check mark, this gives both of us reputation).